# Want to copy / rename files via MSBuild target in .NET Core project file but I don't know how

Tags: msbuild

I have a solution with one loader project and multiple plugin projects.  I'd like to copy files like "State1.json" and "State2.json" from a particular plugin project to a "bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Plugins" folder in the Loader project, prefixing the name of the plugin project files (i.e. "Plugin1.State1.json") but I'm unsure how to do so.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the answer on my own:

```
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <ItemGroup>
      <StateFiles Include="State\*.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(StateFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(StateFiles->'$(SolutionDir)Loader\$(OutDir)Plugins\$(ProjectName)_%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>
```